# How to only accept echeck with Authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net, payment-processing

I'm using Authorize.net's hosted form and CIM. We have an application where we only want to accept echeck and NOT credit card.

Is this possible to turn off the credit card option on the hosted form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The payment types that appear on your CIM hosted payment form are controlled by your gateway account.  If credit cards are disabled and eCheck.Net is enabled, only the eCheck option would appear on the form.

You cannot configure this yourself, it must be done by Authorize.Net Customer Support for production accounts.

If you want to test this with your sandbox account, use the form at 
http://developer.authorize.net/support to make the request.  Be sure to specify applicable sandbox account number or API Login.